# C# Searching through HTML

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I have written a few programs over the last few months that load HTML pages into a string and does various things like extract bits and pieces. I was basically writing my own GUI for some websites which have no API.

I've done this by stringing together many `String.Substring()`, `String.IndexOf()`, and `String.LastIndexOf()` statements.

I realise this is probably not the best way to do it - I was just writing a few "quick-and-dirty" trials to begin with.

What is the proper way to extract tokens from a web page?
Thanks :)

Comment: Top-right corner. A white box with the word "search" as a placeholder. @Ozzah That's the thing you want. :)

Comment: @bzlm I don't think that's exactly what I want, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XHTML, load it into XmlDocument or XDoxument.

For (non-X)HTML, load it into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)'s HtmlDocument - the API is almost the same as XmlDocument, so it should be familiar.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)